# Sort arrays by "width x height" pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Pattern look like `width x height`

```
var formats = [
"900x100",
"900x200",
"1200x200",
"1200x100",
"1100x100",
"1100x200"
];
```

**Result will be :**

```
"1200x200",
"1200x100",
"1100x200",
"1100x100",
"900x200",
"900x100"
```

First sort `width` then sort `height`

via using `.sort()` ?

```
formats.sort(function(a,b){
   // do something
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/oGEroJI/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsbin.com/oGEroJI/3/edit?js,console

```
formats.sort(function(a,b){
   var a = a.split("x");
   var b = b.split("x");
  if (a[0] !== b[0]) {
    return b[0] - a[0]; // by width
  } else {
    return b[1] - a[1]; // by height
  }
});
```

Comment: Shorter version: 
   `return b[0] === a[0] ? b[1]-a[1] : b[0]-a[0];`

Comment: If you're interested in these kinds of silly optimizations check out the `code-golf` tag, otherwise please keep it professional. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf